# Create database in Google Cloud Platform (Second Generation SQL instance)

Tags: django, google-app-engine

For [first generation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction?hl=en_US&_ga=1.93841621.99683571.1450974413#features) SQL instances, it is possible to create databases. For [Second Generation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction?hl=en_US&_ga=1.93841621.99683571.1450974413#v2), there seems to be no option to create a database. How does this work? What is an SQL instance without databases?

And more importantly: how do I integrate that with my django project? I need to setup the following:

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/my-project-id',
            'NAME': 'foobar', # TODO: what to put here?
            'USER': 'root',
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to find out:

Second Generation SQL instances are normal MySQL instances (as are First Generation instances), but the user interface in the Google Cloud Platform does not allow for the same operations that are available for First Generation instances. For example:

- you can not create databases
- you can not create user accounts

To do that you will need to connect with a mysql client, and do it manually. For that you will need to:

- setup a root password
- authorize remote networks